# Can an ip based virtual host be followed by an endpoint to point to a different website on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

What I'm wanting to do for testing multiple applications is set up Nginx to have one app at **210.32.45.189/foo** and another at **210.32.45.189/bar**. Is this possible? I don't know how to configure the server_name directive in my sites-available file.

Comment: Will this be the only virtual host in `nginx`?

Comment: No, I would like to be able to have multiple applications. Each one In would like to be able to have as a different endpoint. For example, 210.32.45.189/app1 would point to a specific app, and 210.32.45.189/app2 would point to another. I know I could do this by utilizing different ports, but for security purposes I would just like to allow only http requests on port 80 and just have different endpoints for each app.

Comment: Without a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, I am not sure how to answer

Comment: Ok, I am serving up a Flask application using Python and uWSGI. I have more than one flask app. I want app1 to be accessible through 210.32.45.189/app1 and I want app2 to be accessible through 210.32.45.189/app2  I want to be able to do this without having to map each app through a different port number. I want all the requests to come through on port 80

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, this is the best I can think of.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 210.32.45.189;

        location /foo {
                ...
        }
        location /bar {
                ...
        }
}
```